# Convert decimal data values to month year text

Tags: sql, db2, iseries-navigator

I am given a table where the month is stored as a decimal value in one column, the year as a decimal in another column. In my query I want to return a text version of the month and year, such as...

from the database 2 and 2020
I want to display February 2020.

I started with...

```
date(concat(concat(concat(varchar(BDYREARN), '-'), varchar(BDMOEARN)), '-1')) AS Date_Earned
```

and was going to then use

```
monthName(Date_Earned)
```

but this feels like a very long way to go to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TO_CHAR(DATE(DIGITS(DEC(BDYREARN, 4)) || '-' || DIGITS(DEC(BDMOEARN, 2)) || '-01'), 'Month YYYY')
```

Comment: Thanks. Same basic idea but this is cleaner than concat multiple strings. Build a date object and then make it a string at the end.

Comment: Since the months don't change from year to year, you could replace `DIGITS(DEC(BDYREARN, 4)) || '-'` with `'2020-'`